# Ошибка в коде бота

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True )
async def event_role(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    message = client.get_channel(804124032072810497) 
    role_mode = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 762383110020923422)
    role_sold = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 690300847321776479)
    role_acad = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 797928464874864641)
    role_olds = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 711702722088534079)
    role_noro = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 722222395686912053)
    role_brot = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 690301338755661895)
    role_toxi = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 697068293034606642)
    role_figh = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 690301478941884447)
    role_tank = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 690303335181320324)
    role_csgo = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 690303455859966094)
    role_samp = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 690304421887868968)
    role_dota = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 744649084450898002)
    msg = await message.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'**{ctx.author.mention} Запустил евент на выдачу ролей участнику сервера: {member.mention}.**\n Чтобы выдать ему роль нажмите на одну из реакций.\n**{role_sold.mention} - \n {role_acad.mention} - \n {role_olds.mention} - \n {role_noro.mention} - \n {role_brot.mention} - \n {role_toxi.mention} - \n {role_figh.mention} - \n {role_tank.mention} - \n {role_csgo.mention} - \n {role_samp.mention} - \n {role_dota.mention} - ️**', color=0xff00f6))
    await msg.add_reaction('') #sold
    await msg.add_reaction('') #acad
    await msg.add_reaction('') #olds
    await msg.add_reaction('') #noro
    await msg.add_reaction('') #brot
    await msg.add_reaction('') #toxi
    await msg.add_reaction('') #figh
    await msg.add_reaction('') #tank
    await msg.add_reaction('') #csgo
    await msg.add_reaction('') #samp
    await msg.add_reaction('️') #dota


    def checkuser(reaction, user):
        if 762383110020923422 in [y.id for y in message.author.roles]:
            return user == message.author

    while True:
        try:
            on_reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 1200, check = checkuser)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.send(embed = discord.Embed(discription = f'{author.mention}**, cook dela**'))
        else:
            if str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_sold)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_acad)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_olds)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_noro)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_brot)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_toxi)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_figh)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_tank)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_csgo)
            elif str(reaction) == "":
                await member.add_roles(role_samp)
            elif str(reaction) == "️":
                await member.add_roles(role_dota)
```

Сама ошибка

```
Logged in as
Ignoring exception in command event_role:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\soldatov bot\prikolist.py", line 220, in event_role
    on_reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 1200, check = checkuser)
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 478, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 370, in dispatch
    result = condition(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\soldatov bot\prikolist.py", line 215, in checkuser
    if 762383110020923422 in [y.id for y in message.author.roles]:
AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'author'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MrArt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Comment: Кстати НЕ НАДО так писать код. Ну есть же циклы! Есть же словари. Средства языка даны, чтоб код было проще понять, удобней читать (и ⇒ дебажить) и расширять.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user.bot == False  and reaction.message.id == yvedom.id and (str(reaction) in control_emojis) and rolestmod or roledevel or rolemaste in user.roles
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `message` у вас является объектом класса TextChannel, а не Member/User.
Строка, в которой была допущена ошибка (звёздочками выделю ошибку):

```
def checkuser(reaction, user):
        if 762383110020923422 in [y.id for y in **message.author.roles**]:
            return user == message.author
```